# Copying duplicating issue

Tags: excel, vba

i wrote the next code to copy a certain worksheet from my active workbook to multiple woorkbooks but it keeps duplicating the copies,thats my first problem,
the next one i want that code to effect the folder and subfolders inside it how to do it.
the code is:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination workbook
    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("pay")
    'Folder containing the destination workbooks
    folder = "J:\2021\hager\test\"
    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy after:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=sourceWorkbook.Name, NewName:=destinationWorkbook.Name
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Wend
End Sub
```

as pay is the worksheet and the folder is my targeted folder .

Comment: Please, better clarify what "it keeps duplicating the copies" means. Then, your active code will update the workbooks in the defined folder, but not in its sub folders.

Comment: i mean it keeps duplicating the worksheet i wanted to copy ,like make alot of copies in the targeted workbook  pay1,pay2,pay3 and so;and am asking is there a way to make it effect the workbooks in the subfolders aswell .

Comment: I can show you how to update all workbooks from folders and sub folders (a very fast way), but it looks that your installation has a problem. If you use `sourceSheet.Copy` without any parameter after, Excel creates a new workbook containing only the copied sheet. But if you use `sourceSheet.Copy after:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)` it shouldn't behave in this way... Let me point you to the method description. Please, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.copy). What Excel/Office version do you use?

Comment: office 2016 and like the code above am already using sourceSheet.Copy after:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1) but i don'tknow why it keeps duplicating sheets sometimes it can be more than 10 sheets in the same workbook

Comment: Please, better clarify this issue... Are there more than 10 **workbooks containing only the copied sheet**, or only **duplicated sheets**? If the last variant, where those sheets are?

Comment: I can show you how to update all workbooks from folders and sub folders (a very fast way) ;  i will be very grateful if you could this please.

Comment: i mean it's duplicating the same sheet am copying to the targeted workbooks more than 10 times like every workbook in the targeted file contains pay1,pay2,pay ......    and so

Comment: Are you sure that this is happening? Didn't you run the code many times and it, of course, copy it as many times you run it? Try adding one code lines twice in order to test that, please: `Debug.print destinationWorkbook.Name, destinationWorkbook.Worksheets.count` before copying the sheet and after. What do you find in `Immediate Window` after running the code, **for each updated workbook**? Isn't it only a sheet added (second `sheets.count` being bigger with a unit then the first one)?

Comment: i ran it in two different folders one ran just 1 time and the other folder ran in some workbooks for 7 times and some 8 times .

Comment: I cannot understand that... Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: its an local folder

Comment: What does the line Debug.Print folder & filename produce in the immediate window ?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next function, which will return an array of all files matching the ".xls*" extension criteria:

```
Private Function allFiles(strFold As String, Optional ext As String = "") As Variant 'super, super fast...
  Dim arr
  arr = Filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & """ /b /s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")
  If ext <> "" Then
    Dim arrFin, arrExt, El, i As Long
    ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr))
      For Each El In arr
         arrExt = Split(El, ".")
         If arrExt(UBound(arrExt)) Like ext Then
             arrFin(i) = El: i = i + 1
         End If
      Next El
      ReDim Preserve arrFin(i - 1)
      allFiles = arrFin
  Else
      allFiles = arr
  End If
End Function
```

Then use it in your code in the next way:

```
Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook, sourceSheet As Worksheet, destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim folder As String, arr, El
    
    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination workbook
    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("pay")
    'Folder containing the destination workbooks
    folder = "J:\2021\hager\test\"
    arr = allFiles(folder, "xls*")
    For Each El In arr
        Debug.Print El: Stop 'run the code line by line pressing F8
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(El)
        sourceSheet.copy After:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=sourceWorkbook.Name, newName:=destinationWorkbook.Name
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
    Next El
End Sub
```

When the above code will stop on the line `Debug.Print El`, run it line by line, pressing `F8` and see what happends. If ie work as you need, please comment the code line in discussion and press `F5` to run all of it.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: actually i couldn't run the private function sorry .

Comment: @Mohamed Nabil **Where from try you running it**? I mean in which code modulee? Then make it Public... But it should exist in a **standard module**! And the `Sub` calling it should also be there... Do you understand what this mean?

Comment: i added it to the modules and try to run it from the formulas tab

Comment: @Mohamed What running from **the formula tab**? Do you try using the function as a UDF one? How did you call your previous `Sub`? Please, write here what you were using. You should use the same call! The `Sub` is calling the function...

Comment: @Mohamed What running from **the formula tab**? Do you try using the function as a UDF one? How did you call your previous `Sub`? Please, write here what you were using. You should use the same call! The `Sub` is calling the function... Please, try adding a button/shape on one sheet, assign the sub `CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder` to it and press it. In order to assign a `Sub`, try right click -> Assign macro... (set 'Macros In: This Workbook) and select the respective one...

Comment: actually am not that good with vba i don't know what to do with that function .

Comment: @Mohamed I asked you clearly: **How did you call your previous Sub?**. So, do it in the same way. The single condition is that the `Sub` to be in the same module as the `Function`. Is it something unclear about that? If not something confidential, can you share your workbook where the code exists? You can send it on my personal mail (see it in my profile) or on a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one easy to be used...

Comment: `arr = allFiles(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\", "xls*")` should that be folder ie `J:\2021\hager\test\\`?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/d6r62o this is the original file

Comment: @CDP1802 Of course... I tested the code in that way and I only adapted `folder` variable. I will modify it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mohamed Before looking to your workbook, please test the updated code.

Comment: @Mohamed Nabil Please test the updated workbook. You can download it from [here](https://easyupload.io/2p20ct). **Your workbook did not contain  my code**! So, I couldn't understand how you tested it. You must learn that you cannot have three Subs having the same name... I modified mine name. I inserted a button on the first  sheet (le left one...) having the caption "Update Workbooks". Please click it, see what's happening and send some feedback.

Comment: i tested it and it gave me error 1004 can't find the path .

Comment: @Mohamed Nabil But, did you update the path with the Arabic characters, as I could see it in the other existing Subs? The new module is named "Correct_Module". I can see the path "J:\2021\hager\ÇáÓæíÓ ÇáÓÎäå\Èäß\", but the VBA editor, in my localization cannot read Arabic. Probably, yours can. If not, write it in a cell ("A1" of first sheet) and use `folder = worksheets(1).Range("A1").value`.  I can see it being empty now...

Comment: same result don't know why !!!

Comment: @Mohamed Nabil But the error is obvious... If you are not able to supply the correct folder path (**ending in "\"**), the code cannot know what you want... Did you try using the one you said that your code works, but with some problems? Try going in the folder you want, right click on a file there, choose Properties and copy the address from 'Location:'...

Comment: i did a lot of things still the same error .

Comment: @Mohamed Nabil I did everything I could in order to help you. The code works on my computer. If you receive that error, it is obvious a matter of folder name. Do you have AnyDesk installed? The single thing I can try is to connect to your computer and see what's happening...

Comment: thx a lot buddy i really appreciate your effort  and everyone in here were very helpful thx ^_^ .

Answer (score 0):

### Add Worksheet to Multiple Files

- This will copy an active workbook's worksheet to all relevant (`.xlsx`) files in a folder and all of its subfolders (`/s`).
- It will skip the files already containing the worksheet.
- If the code is in the workbook containing the worksheet (`Pay`), replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Const ProcName As String = "CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const dFolderPath As String = "J:\2021\hager\test\"
    Const dFilePattern As String = "*.xlsx"
    Const swsName As String = "Pay"
    
    Dim fCount As Long
    
    Dim dFilePaths() As String
    dFilePaths = ArrFilePaths(dFolderPath, dFilePattern)
    If UBound(dFilePaths) = -1 Then Exit Sub ' no files found
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook ' ThisWorkbook ' 
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsName)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(dFilePaths)
        Debug.Print "Opening... " & dFilePaths(n)
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePaths(n))
        If Not SheetExists(dwb, swsName) Then
            sws.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(1)
            'dwb.ChangeLink swb.Name, dwb.Name ' doesn't work for me
            fCount = fCount + 1
            Debug.Print "Worksheet added to... " & fCount & ". " & dFilePaths(n)
        End If
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next n
    
    MsgBox "Worksheet inserted in " & fCount & " workbook(s).", vbInformation

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Rte '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the file paths of the files of a folder in an array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*.*", _
    Optional ByVal DirSwitches As String = "/s/b/a-d") _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrFilePaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
    Dim ExecString As String ' '%comspec%' or 'cmd.exe' ?
    ExecString = "%comspec% /c Dir """ _
        & FolderPath & FilePattern & """ " & DirSwitches
    Dim Arr() As String: Arr = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
        .Exec(ExecString).StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) - 1)
    End If
    ArrFilePaths = arr

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Rte '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating wether a sheet, defined
'               by its name ('SheetName'), exists in a workbook ('wb').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function SheetExists( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal SheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim Sh As Object: Set Sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    SheetExists = True
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: it didn't have any effect sorry.

Comment: What does that mean? Do you get a message? What is written in the `Immediate window` `Ctrl+G`? Also, at the beginning of my post, it says when it will work.

Comment: i did what u said but it saying it can't find the path .

Comment: I have modified my answer a few times. Try to copy the code once more.

Comment: still giving me the same error ; will it do so coz i changed the language???

Answer (score 0):

This loops through workbooks in the folder and subfolders. It only copies the `pay` sheet if it doesn't exist.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()

    Const WS_NAME = "pay"
    Const folder = "J:\2021\hager\test\" ' destination workbooks

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim FSO As Object, ts As Object
    Dim flds As Collection, fld As Object, f As Object
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, bExists As Boolean, logfile As String
    
    ' logfile
    logfile = Format(Now, "yyyyddmm_HHMMSS") & "_log.txt"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.createTextFile(logfile)
    
    Set wbSrc = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    Set flds = New Collection
    
    If FSO.FolderExists(folder) Then
    
      ' collection of folders and subfolders
       Call GetFolders(FSO, folder, flds)
       
       'scan folders
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       For i = 1 To flds.Count
            ts.writeLine "---- Folder = " & flds(i)
            ' scan folder for files
            For Each f In flds(i).Files
               
                If f.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
                    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
                    
                    ' check if sheet already exists
                    bExists = False
                    For Each wsDest In wbDest.Sheets
                        If wsDest.Name = WS_NAME Then
                            bExists = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
             
                    ' copy sheet if not exists
                    If bExists = False Then
                        wsSrc.Copy after:=wbDest.Sheets(1)
                        wbDest.ChangeLink Name:=wbSrc.Name, NewName:=wbDest.Name
                        wbDest.Close savechanges:=True
                        n = n + 1
                        ts.writeLine f.Path & " inserted " & WS_NAME
                    Else
                        wbDest.Close savechanges:=False
                        ts.writeLine f.Path & " existing sheet " & WS_NAME
                    End If
                Else
                    ts.writeLine f.Path & " Skipped"
                End If
            Next
        Next
        MsgBox n & " sheets inserted see " & logfile, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder : " & folder, vbCritical, "Folder not found"
    End If
    ts.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True   
End Sub

Sub GetFolders(FSO, s As String, ByRef flds)
    Dim fld As Object
    Set fld = FSO.getfolder(s)
    flds.Add fld
    For Each fld In fld.subfolders
        Call GetFolders(FSO, fld.Path, flds) ' recurse
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this one worked with me bro thx a lot ,but can it be on all sub level.

Comment: @mohamed ok see updated code and new subroutine GetFolders.