# Get file names from folder and subfolder function change

Tags: excel, vba, function, file, filesystemobject

i have this code below to get files names from a specific folder and it works great. i like how is transposes the file names it works really well with how i do my work.

what i want to change is to have it also return the file names with in the subfolders to. but carry on transposing it accrss my work sheet.

Thank you.

```
Function GetFileNames6(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Variant
Dim Result As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyFile As Object
Dim MyFSO As Object
Dim myFolder As Object
Dim MyFiles As Object
Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
Set MyFiles = myFolder.Files
ReDim Result(1 To MyFiles.Count)
i = 1
o = 1
For Each MyFile In MyFiles
Result(i) = MyFile.name & " " & MyFile.DateCreated
i = i + 1

Next MyFile
GetFileNames6 = Result

End Function
```

Comment: You could try `ArrFilePaths`, a faster option found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70487156) (scroll down a little bit).

Comment: im not to sure how to change it so it would work like my current function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return File Names From All Folders and Subfolders

**Issues**

- Files containing 'non-standard' characters like e.g. `žćčšđ` will be returned by the `ArrFilePaths` function using the `WScript Host` but will not be found by the `FileSystemObject object` (nor the `Dir` function) hence the complications in the `GetFileNames6`function. If you have such characters in your file- or folder names, you can ask another question.
- I've used something like `Dim Arr() As String: Arr = Split("")` to get an 'empty' string array in both functions. Not sure if that's the ideal way since I've never seen it done before.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Tests the 'GetFileNames6' function.
' Calls:        GetFileNames6
'                   ArrFilePaths
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub GetFileNames6TEST()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
     
    Dim NamesDates() As String: NamesDates = GetFileNames6(FolderPath)
    
    If UBound(NamesDates) = -1 Then
        Debug.Print "No files found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Debug.Print Join(NamesDates, vbLf)
   
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a zero-based string array containing the concatenated
'               names and dates ('DateCreated') from a given zero-based string
'               array containing file paths.
' Calls:        ArrFilePaths.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetFileNames6( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") _
As String()
    Const ProcName As String = "GetFileNames6"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Ensuring that a string array is passed if an error occurs.
    GetFileNames6 = Split("") ' LB = 0 , UB = -1
    
    Dim FilePaths() As String: FilePaths = ArrFilePaths(FolderPath)
    'Debug.Print Join(FilePaths, vbLf)
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    Dim n As Long ' Files Count
    Dim fCount As Long ' Found Files Count
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(FilePaths)
        If fso.FileExists(FilePaths(n)) Then
            Set fsoFile = fso.GetFile(FilePaths(n))
            FilePaths(fCount) = fsoFile.Name & Delimiter & fsoFile.DateCreated
            fCount = fCount + 1
        Else ' happens if not 'standard characters' (character map?)
            Debug.Print "Not found:             " & FilePaths(n)
        End If
    Next n
        
    If fCount < n Then
        ReDim Preserve FilePaths(0 To fCount - 1)
        'Debug.Print Join(FilePaths, vbLf)
        Debug.Print "Initially found files: " & n
        Debug.Print "Finally found files:   " & fCount
    End If
        
    GetFileNames6 = FilePaths

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the file paths of the files in a folder in an array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*.*", _
    Optional ByVal DirSwitches As String = "/s/b/a-d") _
As String()
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrFilePaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Ensuring that a string array is passed if an error occurs.
    ArrFilePaths = Split("") ' LB = 0 , UB = -1
   
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
    Dim ExecString As String ' '%comspec%' or 'cmd.exe' ?
    ExecString = "%comspec% /c Dir """ _
        & FolderPath & FilePattern & """ " & DirSwitches
    Dim Arr() As String: Arr = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
        .Exec(ExecString).StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    If UBound(Arr) > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To UBound(Arr) - 1)
    End If
    ArrFilePaths = Arr

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: You sir Are an amazing person thank you so much

Comment: hi again this code its great but is there a way to stop it running everytime i run another macro? as soon as i try to use another macro if has to upate this first. all help greatly appreciated